# How do I use favicon with the Hugo Future Imperfect Slim theme in blogdown?

Tags: favicon, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to generate a favicon for a site I am building in blogdown and I am confused about how to insert it correctly. As a relatively new blogdown user I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop it here

`/yoursite/static/favicon.ico`